# How to run NSTimer or scheduled process that repeats, while responding to user interaction

Tags: ios, nstimer, background-process

When I use

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:intervalCountDownTimer target:self selector:@selector(updateCountDownDurationForTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

It gets paused if I scroll a `UITableView`. It resumes only after scrolling is stopped.

My tableView does use `dispatch_async & dispatch_sync` to load images asynchronously, I'm not sure if this is the main cause.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            FXDMediaItem *mediaItem = [self mediaItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            if (mediaItem) {
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    cell.imageviewAlbumArt.image = [mediaItem albumArtImage];
                });
            }
        });
```

I've been looking for the way to run this timer in background mode, but couldn't find the right solution. It doesn't have to be a `NSTimer`, but I need to use **a scheduled repeated process**.

I suspect the answer might be actually an easy one, but can't find it

Comment: `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{` should be a `dispatch_async()` Doesn't answer you question but there is no need to do a synchronous dispatch here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that by creating your timer with scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector: userInfo:repeats: adds it to the main run loop in the default mode. This seems to get paused when scrolling a UITableView (actually a UIScrollView). The trick here is to add your timer to the main run loop with a different mode, as follows:

```
timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:intervalCountDownTimer target:self selector:@selector(updateCountDownDurationForTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Comment: THIS IS EXACTLY WHAT I'VE BEEN LOOKING FOR. Thanks @ian

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using GCD for background work, try putting what's inside `updateCountDownDurationForTimer:` in a background thread.

Comment: After researching more about this, I realized I need to be able to cancel. Will GCD still be able to help me on this?

Comment: Well, repeating timers should have a reference and should be invalidated (cancelled), on which thread you do it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

As for your timer, have you looked at [dispatch_source_create()](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_source_create)?

I assume you are updating a label or something, right? Update the label in the `-scrollViewDidScroll:` while the table view is scrolling, keep your timer while it is not.

If I am wrong about my assumptions, please post some code of what you're doing in your timer and I'll update my answer accordingly.